# Regex Detect Repeated Characters

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex to detect repeated characters in a string.

For example:

`abca` should found **a**bc**a**.

Or

`foofbarbar` should found **f**oo**f** **barbar**

I tried to use `\(.+)\1\` but I don't know why it's not working.

Any idea for this Regex?

Comment: Not sure, try [`(.+).*(\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/p3sVrk/1).

Comment: Why don't you want it to find `oo` in `foofbarbar`? Do you not want to match repeated characters if they are right next to each other?